# changing the default structure of category & tag permalinks

Tags: permalinks

I would like to remove the "category" part of my catergory permalinks structures. I know you can replace this base by using another word, but I want no words.

So, now I have website.com/category/france
What I want is: website.com/france

Leaving this empty doesn't help. I guess the default setting is to add the word category to the base of the permalink. [image]I think I have to change the default setting for the category permalink base, but I don't know where/how in my functions file.

(I have the same problem with tags)

Would really appreciate some help

Answer (score 0):

I found an easy fix. In case anyone else has this problem: if you have the Yoast SEO plugin installed you can remove the "category" base from category permalinks in your Yoast SEO settings.